# asyncio create_task to run forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have the following code

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def while_loop():
    n = 0
    while True:
        print(f"{n}")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        n = n+1

async def some_func():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Some Func")

future = loop.create_task(while_loop())
loop.run_until_complete(some_func())
```

I expected the `while_loop` function to run forever but it seems to only executes as a result of calling `run_until_complete` and it stops printing the while loop once `some_func` is finished executing. The output I see is:

```
0
1
2
Some Func
```

I expected the numbers to keep printing even after `some_func` is completed.

```
0
1
2
Some Func
3
4
5
6
.
.
.
```

The only way to get more numbers printed is to call `some_func` again.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I expected the numbers to keep printing even after `some_func` is completed.

The argument to `run_until_complete` controls how long the event loop is run. And once the event loop stops running, *all* coroutines are effectively suspended, not just the one that you've been waiting for. But you do have different options:

- `loop.run_until_complete(some_func())` - what you already used; run the event loop until the `some_func` coroutine finishes. Executes other coroutines in parallel during that time as well, but also stops executing them as soon as the event loop finishes.
- [`loop.run_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever) - run the event loop until some coroutine or callback invokes `loop.stop()`. If none of them do that, then the event loop will not halt, even if all the coroutines come to an end. In your case you'd call `loop.create_task(while_loop())` followed by `loop.create_task(some_func())` and then `loop.run_forever()`.
- `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(while_loop(), some_func()))` run the event loop until *both* the specified coroutines finish. This (wait for *all* the tasks) is apparently what you expected `loop.run_until_complete()` to do automatically even if you name only one, except it doesn't work like that, it stops as soon as the specified coroutine finishes. [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) can be used to wait for multiple coroutines at once. For a more fine-tuned control of waiting, also see [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait).

Since one of your coroutines runs forever, the last two options will be equivalent and will result in the expected output.

Comment: Now, if I wanted to run `some_func` (and other functions) later at some random time then would it be best to run a new loop in a separate thread? Otherwise, `run_forever` is blocking the main thread loop.

Comment: @slaw Consider that coroutines can start other coroutines. Thus the fact you've invoked `run_forever` doesn't mean that the whole program is stuck or that you can't add new things for the event loop to do. A typical asyncio program is structured around the event loop which services the whole application. The whole thing with the event loop in a background thread is only needed if you need to introduce asyncio into a legacy code base (which the question doesn't indicate).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if I am seeing strange behavior as I am testing my code inside of a Jupyter notebook. loop.run_forever() blocks indefinitely the moment I execute it after loop.get_event_loop(). I expected to execute loop.run_forever() and then be able to create tasks afterward that get added to the loop. Is this the wrong way to think about it? Essentially, I am exploring data retrieved from a RESTful API but I don’t know apriori how that data is laid out. So I hit 1,000 urls to collect the data, then analyze it to know where other endpoints I might want to grab next.

Comment: @slaw Keep in mind that asyncio is not threaded - you cannot at the same time finish with `run_until_complete()` and have the numbers keep printing. asyncio is designed for the whole program to run within the event loop. So if you are exploring data retrieved using REST, then write a coroutine that retrieves the data and analyzes it (by spawning other coroutines if needed). This coroutine can consist of a simple `while True` loop, or it can contain arbitrarily complex logic. Start the coroutine using `loop.create_task()`, run `loop.run_forever()`, and let it do the rest.

Comment: Finally a clear explanation of how to go about adding tasks to the loop after `run_until_complete()` blocks the main thread.

Comment: If using  `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(a(), b()))` , will the event loop still wait until `b()` finish when an exception is raised in `a()`?

Comment: @chanp That's a good question. I'd expect the answer to be "no", and [this test](https://pastebin.com/PvwUqfgk) confirms that expectation.