# use of run_coroutine_threadsafe in aysncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm very surprised why the below code is not working?
Can anyone please tell?

I'm trying to call run_coroutine_threadsafe in another thread, but it is giving me error -
Exception in thread my_thread:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/sample1.py", line 17, in hello
    y = x.result()
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 438, in result
    raise CancelledError()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

```
import asyncio
import threading


async def hel():
    return 4


class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.my_thread = threading.Thread(name='my_thread', target=self.hello)
        self.my_thread.start()

    def hello(self):
        x = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(hel(), self.loop)
        y = x.result()
        print(y)


async def h():
    Hello()

asyncio.run(h())
```

Comment: The event loop ends when `h()` completes, so x gets cancelled. With the current code layout, you need to somehow "await" the thread from within `h()` (not impossible, but potentially awkward), or change how the event loop is ran. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113979/2840436 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592692/2840436

Comment: You are trying to run hel() in the main event loop, but h() is the only task and it does not contain any await expression.  When h() finishes the event loop closes; that's what `asyncio.run()` does.  Add one line: `await asyncio.sleep(0)` after `Hello()`.  The await expression allows another task to run, so you will see "4" on the console.

Comment: Thanks @micromoses , great observation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paul Cornelius the below code working good.

```
import asyncio
import threading


async def hel():
    return 4


class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.my_thread = threading.Thread(name='my_thread', target=self.hello)
        self.my_thread.start()

    def hello(self):
        x = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(hel(), self.loop)
        y = x.result()
        print(y)


async def h():
    Hello()
    asyncio.sleep(0)

asyncio.run(h())
```